# Trying to map array from store but getting TypeError: *array*.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-redux

I'm making async request in one component and dispatching the result to store. Result is array of objects. Than in other component i'm trying to map it into  tag.

The problem is that i'm getting type error because initial state for my reducer is null and null cant be mapped. Tried to change it to just empty array but getting same error.

My reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  currentSearchResult: [],
};

const OrgsListReducer = (state = initialState, action) => action.type === 'GET_ORGS_LIST' ? action.payload : state;
```

payload itself is ok

My component:

```
class OrgList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoaded: false,
            orgList: this.props.currentSearchResult,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.currentSearchResult !== []) {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true
            })
           }
       }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.currentSearchResult);
        return this.state.isLoaded ?
            <ul>
                {this.state.orgList.map((org) =>
                    <li key={org.id}>{org.login}</li>
                )}
            </ul>
            :
            <h1>Loading...</h1>
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        currentSearchResult: state.currentSearchResult
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(OrgList)
```

Comment: In your store, what did you define as the key of the reducer for that reducer `currentSearchResult`?

Answer (score 0):

remove `this` in constructor

```
this.state = {
    isLoaded: false,
    orgList: props.currentSearchResult,
}
```

But why use the redux value back in state? You can just use the redux value right away.

You have an empty arrangement of `currentSearchResult`'s default, so it will work without a problem even when there is no value.

```
<ul>
    {this.props.currentSearchResult.map((org) =>
         <li key={org.id}>{org.login}</li>
    )}
</ul>
```

Comment: Check constructor tab in https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html. They are not encouraged to write like this in their official guide

Answer (score 0):

If `action.payload` is array and you want to put it in `state.currentSearchResult` you should do like this

```
const OrgsListReducer = (state = initialState, action) => action.type === 'GET_ORGS_LIST' ? {currentSearchResult: action.payload } : state;
```

`state` is by itself object, which contain just one property `currentSearchResult`. So you should assign array to `currentSearchResult`. So state structure will not be modified.

Also `this.props.currentSearchResult !== []` will always be `true`. [Array is object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) in JavaScript. Object equal only when the [same object compared to itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#A_model_for_understanding_equality_comparisons). As you want to check if array is empty, do `this.props.currentSearchResult.length > 0`